# Setting up Stamplay CLI locally to use stamplay init and stamplay deploy

Tags: angularjs, hosting, stamplay

I am having a bit of trouble getting everything setup locally. Stamplay's command isn't doing anything.
I have installed it using `npm install -g stamplay-cli`, but `stamplay init` and `stamplay deploy` commands aren't doing anything, any ideas where I might have messed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your npm installation requires super user permissions; you may need the following commands to install the CLI correctly using:

```
sudo npm install -g stamplay-cli
```

Otherwise the error is being caused by your local environment.

I suggest you the follow these steps :

- Re-install Node.js through nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm (nvm is a manger for the node's versions)
- Restart your bash terminal
- Install the Stamplay CLI again with the command: `npm install -g stamplay-cli`